# Node async.map how to call function itself after all tasks completes

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have the following code:

```
function get_status(){
    try {
  /* GET - status */
async.map(['http://url1.com/', 'http://url2.com/', 'http://url3.com/'], function(value, callback) {
     /* GET - request status */
     request.post({
          url: value,
          form: { 'mycustomdata': ""+mycustomdata+"" },
          method: 'POST'}, function(err, res, body) {
               /* CHECK - response */
               if (!err && typeof body !== 'undefined' && res.statusCode == 200) {

                   console.log('get status success...')         
                   callback();
               } else {
                   callback('failed to get status');
               }
          })
    }, function(err, results) {
        if (err) { 
            console.log(err); return false;
        } else {
            console.log('finished...') }
    })
}
```

I need when all three urls in async.map processing is finished(some url respond some not) to call where it outputs 'finished...' and from this output to callthis function again...so that function runs every time all url is processed.

So in short..i need when async.map process all urls to output to console 'finished...' and run same function again.

But i m getting only from console...

```
 get status success... 
 failed to get status..
 get status sucess..
```

i never get called

```
 'finished'...
```

so that i can cal function itsef...could you please light me how it needs to be written?

Answer (score 1):

You're only ever passing in the `err` param to the final callback. I believe, from my last use of async.js, you need to pass in `null` as the first param to continue to the next function, here being the final function. Otherwise is skips to the final function as an error.

```
 callback(null, results);
```

If you want it to call itself again, that's just simple recursion. Wrap the async.map in a function, and when `console.log('finished...')` runs, call the function again.

Comment: i replace callback('failed to get status'); with callback(null, 'failed to get status'); but when all three urls are processed i could not get 'finished'... from console.log...maybe i did not understand you correclty?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i made full example so that you can see what is problem and you can try to change code:

```
var async       = require('async'),
request         = require('request');

var myUrls = [ 'http://56.123.65.86:8080/api/server_status/',
  'http://88.96.42.122:8080/api/server_status/',
  'http://12.23.32.25:8080/api/server_status/',
  'http://251.214.44.58:8080/api/server_status/',
  'http://122.23.32.54:8080/api/server_status/' ]

async.map(myUrls, function(url, callback) {
    console.log('getting url...'+url)
  request(url, function(error, response, html) {
    // Some processing is happening here before the callback is invoked
    if (typeof response !== undefined) {
        console.log('response ok...'+url)
        return callback(null, html)
    } else {
        console.log('response failed...'+url)
        return callback(error, html);
    }
  });
}, function(err, results) {
   if (results) {
       console.log('all finished...')
   }
});
```

I im getting this:

```
getting url...http://56.123.65.86:8080/api/server_status/
getting url...http://88.96.42.122:8080/api/server_status/
getting url...http://12.23.32.25:8080/api/server_status/
getting url...http://251.214.44.58:8080/api/server_status/
getting url...http://122.23.32.54:8080/api/server_status/
```

And need to get this:

```
getting url...http://56.123.65.86:8080/api/server_status/
getting url...http://88.96.42.122:8080/api/server_status/
getting url...http://12.23.32.25:8080/api/server_status/
getting url...http://251.214.44.58:8080/api/server_status/
getting url...http://122.23.32.54:8080/api/server_status/
all finished...
```

I cannot get all finished...so it stays with getting url and that stays forever...so i cannot get idea why is all finished... not triggeret after all items are processed...